# How does plugins return value (boolean) affects other plugin in terms of execution?

Tags: plugin

How does the return value true or false affects other plugins of the same group? Does it prevent other plugins from executing when returning false?

Comment: no. But I presume you’re asking for a reason?

Comment: @jamesgarrett Yes indeed. I'm interested in the reason. And mainly how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The outcome of the plugin output will affect overall process flow but not other plugins.

Examples

- `onContentBeforeSave` is a content event. If you return false, the article will not be saved and the error will be shown to the user.
- `onContentAfterTitle` returns a string value and it will be shown after article title.

However, the execution of other plugins will not be affected by this return value.